# Cannot access the close button on Bootstrap Modal box in selenium

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, cucumber

I am making a program in selenium and it navigates to a client internal website that contains bootstrap modal boxes. I am unable to close the required button after filling the form elements. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYSz3.jpg)

I am using the following code to access the modal box

```
    List<WebElement> containerFrame = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println("IFrame Number is :" + containerFrame.size());

    try {
        WebElement openModal  = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddComment']"));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        openModal.click();


    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("not able to find Image");
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(containerFrame.get(0));
        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cke_1_contents']/textarea"));
        element.sendKeys("This is my comment");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement commentType = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddlCommentTypes']"));
        Select familyListSelect = new Select(commentType);
        familyListSelect.selectByIndex(1);

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("not able to find 1");
    }

    try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(containerFrame.get(1));
    driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    WebElement btnSaveCmt = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnSaveCmt']"));
```

I am unable to locate @id='btnSaveCmt'] that is save comment button in the comment box.

I have also tried following approaches to do so but it didn't helped out

```
new WebDriverWait(driverInstance, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byLocator)).click();
```

The selenium Ide shows that the value of window is 'null' so switching to it is a problem. It has 5 iframes and i am able to access the fields in frame(0). but i can't find save **comment button** on the code.

some html for modal box is

```html
<div class="bandeau-footer col-md-12 colorGrey">
  <div class="row line">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <span id="tooltip0" class="fortooltip-bandeau" data-hasqtip="3">
<a tooltipid="someError0" href="###" title="Click to display more information">
<img alt="Click to display more information" src="/imgOceane/Alarme_93.gif">
</a>
<span id="someError0" class="tooltip0" role="alert" style="display:none">A ticket currently in progress on product</span>
        </span>
        <p class="pull-left">
          <span>Ticket in progress!</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <span id="tooltip1" class="fortooltip-bandeau" data-hasqtip="4">
<a tooltipid="someError1" href="###" title="Click to display more information">
<img alt="Click to display more information" src="/imgOceane/Alarme_93.gif">
</a>
<span id="someError1" class="tooltip1" role="alert" style="display:none">Initiator Grp<>Initial Contact CSC/HD tel no.:</span>
        </span>
        <p class="pull-left">
          <span>Init. Grp.<> Initial Contact CSC/ Sup : CSO DEL SSD L1</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="resize"></div>
<h1 class="hide-access">
<span>OCEANE – xxxx (ticket) - Détails du ticket</span>
</h1>
</div>
<div id="idAddModifyComment" class="displaynone">
  <iframe id="frameidAddModifyComment" tabindex="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <html>

    <head></head>

    <body></body>

    </html>
  </iframe>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="content" class="main-wrapper col-md-12 nopadding" style="margin-top: 263px;">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        < div id = "LBLPJTE"
        class = "center displaynone" > < /div>
<form id="FORMTicCom" name="FORMTicCom" action="/binOceane / Ticket / Detail / TrtTicCom / menuname ? COOKIENAME = ticketOceane.net & NUMFEN = 1 " method="
        post " novalidate="
        novalidate ">
<div>
<input name="
        REFRESHTYP " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        BtnSupp.X " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        CMTCHKBOXID " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        COMMENTROW " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        CmtCallDate " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        CmtCallDateHr " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        CmtCallDateMin " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        CALLBACKDATE " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input name="
        BLNEXPORTATTACHDOC " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
</div>
<div id="
        A1 " class="
        accordion ">
<h2 id="
        Acc1 " class="
        noSelect active " onclick="
        $.CommonFeaturs.accordianToggle " style="
        cursor: pointer;
        ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
<a href="#
        " title="
        Customer details ">
<span>Customer details</span>
<span class="
        hide - access open "> open</span>
</a>
</h2>
<fieldset class="
        displayblock ">
<legend class="
        hide - access ">
<span> Customer details </span>
</legend>
<div class="
        row ">
<div class="
        row center ">
<div class="
        error ">
<div id="
        ErrIconcstErrOri " class="
        form alert error " role="
        alert " style="
        display: none;
        ">
<span id="
        ErrIconcstErrOri0InfoIcon " data-hasqtip="
        5 ">
<a tooltipid="
        ErrIconcstErrOri0InfoIconToolTip " href="###
        " title="
        Click to display more information ">
<span id="
        ErrIconcstErrOri0Message " class="
        blankLine text - left "></span>
<span class="
        hide - access "></span>
</a>
<span id="
        ErrIconcstErrOri0InfoIconToolTip " class="
        tooltip " role="
        alert " style="
        display: none ">Click to display more information</span>
</span>
<div class="
        hide - access "></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 12 ">
<div class="
        line row "> </div>
</div>
<div class="
        line row ">
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<div class="
        line row ">
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<p class="
        text - form bold pull - right ">
<span>Last customer call back the </span>
<span class="
        paddingColon ">:</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 6 nopadding width50 "> </div>
</div>
<div class="
        line row ">
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<label class="
        pull - right " for="
        forcustomerref ">
<span>Customer reference </span>
<span class="
        paddingColon ">:</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 6 nopadding width50 ">
<input id="
        forcustomerref " class="
        readonly readonly large " name="
        ViewData.BodyTicComModel.ClientRef " readonly="
        readonly " type="
        text ">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<div class="
        line row ">
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<label class="
        pull - right " for="
        DatDebAlrtDate ">
<span>Next call back to customer </span>
<span class="
        paddingColon ">:</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 6 nopadding width50 ">
<div id="
        DatDebAlrtMainDiv " class="
        spinner - line ">
<div id="
        DatDebAlrt ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtDate " class="
        readonly dateTextbox dateHasError " maxlength="
        10 " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.Date " otherdateid="
        " readonly="
        readonly " value="
        " type="
        text ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtFormat " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.Format " value="
        M / d / yyyy " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtType " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.Type " value="
        standard " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtTimeOffset " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.TimeOffset " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtUtc " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.Utc " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<label id="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownHourslbl " class="
        hide - access " for="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownHours ">
<span>'Next call back to customer ' (hours)</span>
</label>
<select id="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownHours " disabled="
        disabled " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDateDropDownHoursReadonly ">
<option value="
        0 ">12am</option>
</select>
<span id="
        DatDebAlrtColon " class="
        seperator ">:</span>
<label id="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownMinslbl " class="
        hide - access " for="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownMins ">
<span>'Next call back to customer ' (minutes)</span>
</label>
<select id="
        DatDebAlrtDropDownMins " disabled="
        disabled " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDateDropDownMinsReadOnly ">
<option value="
        0 ">00</option>
</select>
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtHourHidden " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.DropDownHours " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DatDebAlrtMinuteHidden " name="
        ViewData.CallBackDate.DropDownMins " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
</div>
</div>
<input id="
        Callback " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<div class="
        hidden ">
<div id="
        CallBackDateMainDiv " class="
        spinner - line ">
<div id="
        CallBackDate ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateDate " class="
        readonly dateTextbox dateHasError " maxlength="
        10 " name="
        CallBackDate.Date " otherdateid="
        " readonly="
        readonly " value="
        " type="
        text ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateFormat " name="
        CallBackDate.Format " value="
        M / d / yyyy " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateType " name="
        CallBackDate.Type " value="
        standard " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateTimeOffset " name="
        CallBackDate.TimeOffset " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateUtc " name="
        CallBackDate.Utc " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<label id="
        CallBackDateDropDownHourslbl " class="
        hide - access " for="
        CallBackDateDropDownHours ">
<span> (hours)</span>
</label>
<select id="
        CallBackDateDropDownHours " disabled="
        disabled " name="
        CallBackDateDropDownHoursReadonly ">
<option value="
        0 ">12am</option>
</select>
<span id="
        CallBackDateColon " class="
        seperator ">:</span>
<label id="
        CallBackDateDropDownMinslbl " class="
        hide - access " for="
        CallBackDateDropDownMins ">
<span> (minutes)</span>
</label>
<select id="
        CallBackDateDropDownMins " disabled="
        disabled " name="
        CallBackDateDropDownMinsReadOnly ">
<option value="
        0 ">00</option>
</select>
<input id="
        CallBackDateHourHidden " name="
        CallBackDate.DropDownHours " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        CallBackDateMinuteHidden " name="
        CallBackDate.DropDownMins " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
        line row ">
<div class="
        col - md - 6 width50 ">
<label class="
        pull - right " for="
        forthirdpartyref ">
<span>Third party reference </span>
<span class="
        paddingColon ">:</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="
        col - md - 6 nopadding width50 ">
<input id="
        forthirdpartyref " class="
        readonly readonly large " name="
        ViewData.BodyTicComModel.ThirdPartyRef " readonly="
        readonly " type="
        text ">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
        bton - line "> </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div id="
        A2 " class="
        accordion ">
<h2 id="
        Acc2 " class="
        noSelect active " onclick="
        $.CommonFeaturs.accordianToggle " style="
        cursor: pointer;
        ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
<a href="#
        " title="
        External application: DIANA ">
<span>External application : DIANA</span>
<span class="
        hide - access open "> open</span>
</a>
</h2>
<fieldset class="
        displayblock ">
<legend class="
        hide - access ">
<span> External application : DIANA </span>
</legend>
<div class="
        row ">
<iframe id="
        ExternalApp " src="
        " name="
        nmExternalApp " style="
        width: 1180px;
        height: 500px;
        ">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div id="
        A4 " class="
        accordion ">
<h2 id="
        Acc4 " class="
        noSelect active setTableWidth " onclick="
        $.CommonFeaturs.accordianToggle " style="
        cursor: pointer;
        ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
<a href="#
        " title="
        Comments ">
<span>Comments</span>
<span class="
        hide - access open "> open</span>
</a>
</h2>
<fieldset class="
        displayblock error ">
<legend class="
        hide - access ">
<span> Comments </span>
</legend>
<div id="
        ERRCOMMENTS " class="
        row error displaynone ">
<div id="
        ERRCOMMENTS " class="
        form alert error " role="
        alert ">
<span id="
        ERRCOMMENTS0InfoIcon " data-hasqtip="
        6 ">
<a class="
        selectionFocus " tooltipid="
        ERRCOMMENTS0InfoIconToolTip " href="###
        " title="
        Click to display more information ">
<span id="
        ERRCOMMENTS0Message " class="
        blankLine text - left ">No attachment found</span>
</a>
<span id="
        ERRCOMMENTS0InfoIconToolTip " class="
        tooltip " role="
        alert " style="
        display: none ">No attachment found</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
        row flow ">
<table id="
        table_comment " class="
        display table comment_table setTableWidth setBorderWidth ">
<caption class="
        hide - access ">
<span> This table shows various comments </span>
</caption>
<thead>
<tr class="
        commentHeaderBackground ">
<th scope="
        col "></th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        commentHeaderSpan ">
<span class="
        hide - access ">icônes informatives</span>
Comment
</span>
</th>
<th class="
        center " scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_tab_number ">N°</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_form_commentType ">Date</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_form_commentType ">Comment type</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_form_type_of_operation ">Type of operation</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_table_name ">Name</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_fomr_entity ">Entity</span>
</th>
<th scope="
        col ">
<span class="
        _lang_title_attachments ">Attachment</span>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="
        2 "> </td>
<td></td>
<td>
<div id="
        DATFILTREMainDiv " class="
        spinner - line trDate ">
<div id="
        DATFILTRE " class="
        minWidthPx ">
<input id="
        DATFILTREDate " class="
        dateTextbox dateHasError hasDatepicker " data-val="
        true " data-val-dateobjectid="
        DATFILTRE " data-val-dateformat="
        The date format is incorrect " data-val-dateformat-defaultvalue="
        " data-val-dateformat-displaytime="
        false " data-val-dateformat-format="
        mm / dd / yy " data-val-dateformat-hourdropdown="
        DATFILTREDropDownHours " data-val-dateformat-minutedropdown="
        DATFILTREDropDownMins " data-val-dateformat-msgincorrectdate="
        Date: Incorrect date " data-val-dateformat-msgincorrecttime="
        Date: Time mandatory " data-val-dateformat-type="
        standard " data-val-offset="
        0.0 " data-val-utcmode="
        false " maxlength="
        10 " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.Date " otherdateid="
        " value="
        " style="
        margin - top: 0px;
        margin - bottom: 0px;
        " type="
        text ">
<img class="
        ui - datepicker - trigger " src=" / images / calendar.png " alt="
        Input help calendar
        for Date " title="
        Input help calendar
        for Date ">
<input id="
        DATFILTREFormat " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.Format " value="
        M / d / yyyy " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DATFILTREType " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.Type " value="
        standard " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DATFILTRETimeOffset " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.TimeOffset " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DATFILTREUtc " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.Utc " value="
        0 " type="
        hidden ">
<a id="
        DATFILTRECurrentDateImage " class="
        cleanImage " href="###
        " title="
        Fill in Date with the current date ">
<img alt="
        Fill in Date with the current date " src=" / Images / picto - clock.png ">
<span class="
        hide - access ">Fill in Date with the current date</span>
</a>
<a id="
        DATFILTREEraseImage " class="
        cleanImage " href="###
        " title="
        Clear the date Date ">
<img alt="
        Clear the date Date " src=" / images / picto - errase.png ">
<span class="
        hide - access ">Clear the date Date</span>
</a>
<div id="
        DATFILTRE_Error " class="
        error - input form alert error " role="
        alert ">
<a id="
        DATFILTRE_Error0InfoIcon " href="###
        " title="
        ">
<span class="
        span ">
<span class="
        field - validation - valid " data-valmsg-for="
        ViewData.DateFilter.Date " data-valmsg-replace="
        true " role="
        alert "></span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
<input id="
        DATFILTREHourHidden " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.DropDownHours " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
<input id="
        DATFILTREMinuteHidden " name="
        ViewData.DateFilter.DropDownMins " value="
        " type="
        hidden ">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<label class="
        hide - access " for="
        ViewData_BodyTicComModel_CombComProp ">
<span>Comment type</span>
</label>
<select id="
        ViewData_BodyTicComModel_CombComProp " class="
        minwidth100 " name="
        ViewData.BodyTicComModel.CombComProp " onchange="
        $('html').BodyTicCom().refreshPrd('REFRESHTYP')
        ">
<option selected="
        selected " value="
        1 ">User</option>
<option value="
        3 ">Customer</option>
<option value="
        2 ">System</option>
<option value="
        4 ">All</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="
        odd ">
<td class="
        dataTables_empty valign " colspan="
        9 "> Comment list empty. </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="
        legend ">
<h4>
<span class="
        _lang_all_legend ">Legend</span>
</h4>
<ul>
<li>
<span class="
        label ">
<span class="
        puce main "></span>
</span>
<span class="
        _lang_form_comment_main ">Main comment</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="
        label ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
</span>
<p class="
        tkt - comment - sys ">
<span>This font color is used for system comments</span>
</p>
</li>
<li>
<span class="
        label ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
</span>
<p class="
        tkt - comment - client ">
<span>This font color is used for customer comments</span>
</p>
</li>
<li>
<span class="
        label ">
<span class="
        puce "></span>
</span>
<p class="
        comment ">
<span>This font color is used for other comments</span>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add the html of the modal if possible. Recheck you are on the right iframe that contains the button before clicking it, also check the selector is finding the right button. If you can see it and you have the right selector then is the wrong iframe.

Comment: I have tried finding the element in all the iframes by doing containerFrame.get(0 + i) where i is from 0 to 4 for all the iframes but can't find the right iframe. I didn't find any help on google for an answer regarding filling elements in bootstrap modal boxes. It's a popup form box inside the main form.

Comment: Maybe you have an iframe in an iframe, you need to check it step by step, switch -> check element and so on. Please note that if the iframe reloads you might need to switch again.

Comment: i have added the html but i cannot add all of it because of 30000 characters limit. The iframe gets data from database with ajax call.

Comment: For large html you need to use https://jsfiddle.net/ , paste code save and add the url.